# You do not have permission to move the file “xxx.png” to the trash

Tags: ios, xcode, permissions, xcasset

The question is when I move the image in xcassets from 1x to 2x,Xcode pops a tip "You do not have permission to move the file “xxx.png” to the trash.".
Then I tried to chmod the folder xcassets to 777,but it doesn't work.
My Xcode version is 6.0.1,and it happened when I worked with different mac under source control.
Who can help me??Thank u very much!!